# seperate each array value from array passed by ajax -- php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I passed an array using Ajax and i echoed it in php , it works good. But i don't know how to separate its value and find its length.

Here is the code:

```
var myCheckboxes = new Array();
        $(".book_type:checked").each(function() {
           myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
        });

            $.post("s.php?c="+category+"&k="+myCheckboxes,{data : "some data"}, function(response){
   $("#show_result").html(response);
```

And the php is:

```
$a=$_GET['k'];
echo $a;
```

it displays the values of all checkbox like this

```
all,0,1,2,3,4
```

How can i find `$a` length as array?. if i use `sizeof($a)` it shows as 1.
Also how to separate those values into each single value.
Any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try like this

```
$a=$_GET['k'];
$value= explode(",",$a);
echo sizeof($value); //output 6
echo $value[0];      //all
echo $value[1];      //0
echo $value[2];      //1
echo $value[3];      //2
echo $value[4];      //3
echo $value[5];      //4
```

Comment: Yeah..it works...thank you. will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$a=$_GET['k'];
$a=explode(',', $a);
echo count($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value as an array

```
$.post("s.php", {
    data: "some data",
    c: category,
    k: myCheckboxes
}, function (response) {
    $("#show_result").html(response);
})
```

then

```
$a=$_GET['k'];
```

where `$a` will be an array, so `count($a)` should give you the length

Answer (score 0):

You should call [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) in your javascript:

```
//                   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
... category+"&k=" + JSON.stringify(myCheckboxes) ...
```

or, alternatively, use jQuery ajax syntax sugar in your post request:

```
$.post("s.php", { k: myCheckboxes, ... });
```

This will provide a json as string passed to controller. From within your controller you should [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the received parameters:

```
$a = $_GET['k'];
print_r(json_decode($a));
```

Hope this helps.